# Is Oracle killing intranet applets on JRE 7 update 51?

Tags: java, security, applet

Refer to [New security requirements for RIAs in 7u51 (January 2014)](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/new_security_requirements_for_rias) .

> #### RIAs must contain two things:
>
> 1. Code signatures from a trusted authority. All code for Applets and Web Start applications must be signed, regardless of its Permissions attributes.
> 2. Manifest Attributes
>
>    - `Permissions` – Introduced in 7u25, and required as of 7u51. Indicates if the RIA should run within the sandbox or require full-permissions.
>    - `Codebase` – Introduced in 7u25 and optional/encouraged as of 7u51. Points to the known location of the hosted code (e.g. intranet.example.com).

ref another post on stackoverflow, I have the same concern that certificate is expensive for intranet use.
[Sign applet and deploy it in intranet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15523521/sign-applet-and-deploy-it-in-intranet).

I am planning to start a new intranet project, should I give up the consideration on applet?
All of my intranet user do not have the ability to connect outside internet, they are in closed network, I highly doubt the need of signed applet......?

Comment: *"I am planning to start a new intranet project, should I give up the consideration on applet?"*  Avoid applets if humanly possible.  That is advice I've been giving for a long while, before the latest slew of security updates.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: what about javafx? it's a nice technology and I think it runs pretty much the same way as applets.

Comment: *"what about javafx?"*  What about it?  To my eye, it already seems doomed.  I thought it was taking a long time to migrate from *"Here's a GUI toolkit we are playing with - you like?"* to *"This in in the JSE - deal with it"*.  When it came to Java 7 that includes(?) Java-FX, I was surprised that there was no reference to Java-FX classes in the JSE Java Docs.  From that I expected to see it migrated to the Java-Docs in Java 8 at the latest..  But then, I recently read that Oracle was *planning* to incorporate in in Java 9.  ..?!?  Too little, too late, for most people's tastes.

Comment: @DenisTulskiy JavaFX used like an applet is exposed as an applet, so it is really not an *alternative* for applet. (on using it, I tend to agree with [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/433191/365237) - but not with the using applet part :)

Comment: Well probably take a look at WebStart...

Comment: @AndrewThompson IIRC, JavaFX (2) was included in the Oracle JRE but was not in OpenJDK.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline Thanks for the info.  I am leery of using any functionality that has a caveat like *" but was not in ..JDK"* though.  It just does not seem cross-platform if it is not compatible across SDK/JREs.

Comment: @AndrewThompson There are many fine libraries that are not in the JDK.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am planning to start a new intranet project, should I give up the
>   consideration on applet?

Well, yes. Applets haven't been a very good technology choice for a long time, even without Oracles latest changes. If you can do the same using other technologies, that's usually better.

Some reasons:

- continuous stream of vulnerabilities (which is why it should really be disabled by default on browsers)
- resource intensive
- separate access from the web page (act close to plugins)
- deployment isn't very straightforward
- doesn't have the tooling some alternatives have

The most serious reason is the vulnerability issue, but others play a role as well.

> All of my intranet user do not have the ability to connect outside
>   internet, they are in closed network, I highly doubt the need of
>   signed applet......?

It's mandatory in the latest versions of java plugin, so you cannot really help that.

See [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18914650/can-you-sign-a-java-applet-but-keep-it-in-the-sandbox-not-give-it-full-access-t) on what's needed if you would like to keep on going with the applet. If you don't do it, it will not work on the latest versions of java.

Answer (score 4):

As a disclaimer, I am the author of the blog post that you linked to. Intranets are typically known communities where people have reasons to trust each other. If you do not want to purchase a code signing certificate, you can share your public certificate within the small network of trust. This works on an organizational scale but not so much internet-scale.
Also for @TomHawtin above, [OpenJFX](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/openjfx/) is available.

Answer (score 3):

I think another option if you want to stick with Applets would be the promised [Exception Site List](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/upcoming_exception_site_list_in), which should be available in 1.7.0_51 as well, it still means that users need to adjust Java Applet Properties, but at least as far as I understand the post, it will make it possible to allow certain applets on the user machine.

Answer (score 0):

As centic mentioned Dec 6 '13 at 20:23, the Exception Site List is a per user override to allow applets to run.  Oracle help has been updated with this article [How can I configure the Exception Site List](http://java.com/en/download/faq/exception_sitelist.xml).